# load specific channels from mdf (.mf4) file

Tags: python, asammdf

I am loading many large [.mf4](https://www.asam.net/standards/detail/mdf/wiki/) files using the package [asammdf](https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
These files have many channels that I am not interested in and the input is the bottleneck of my program.
So my question is:

Can I somehow only load specific channels from the file to speed up the input process?

What I am doing now is to load the whole file and specify the channels during the conversion to a pandas `Dataframe`.

```
from asammdf import MDF

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'C:/path/to/some/file.mf4'
    mdfObj = MDF(path, version='4.10')
    columns=['A','B','C']
    df = mdfObj.to_dataframe(channels=columns)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using the right methods. When the file is opened only the metadata is loaded, and the actual channel samples are only read as needed (when you call **to_dataframe**).

The bottleneck might be the fact that you do not provide the **raster** argument (see the documentation here https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.to_dataframe) and in this case the output dataframe will be build using the union of all time stamp of the selected channels and doing interpolation for all the columns. Play around with the raster argument

```
from asammdf import MDF

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'C:/path/to/some/file.mf4'
    mdfObj = MDF(path, version='4.10')
    columns=['A','B','C']
    # 0.1s
    df = mdfObj.to_dataframe(channels=columns, raster=0.1)
    # or use the time stamps of channel 'A'
    df = mdfObj.to_dataframe(channels=columns, raster='A')
```

EDIT:
@Jonas Since version 6.1.0 it is possible to make a selective file load by using the `channels` argument https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/development/tips.html#selective-channel-loading

```
from asammdf import MDF

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'C:/path/to/some/file.mf4'
    
    columns=['A','B','C']
    
    mdfObj = MDF(path, channels=columns)
```

Comment: @jonas I've added the posibility to selectively load a MDF file. This will be part of the 6.1.0 release, but right now it is only available in the development branch

Comment: Great tool. I appreciate you putting it together. Can I use a .LAB file that we get from the GUI within the API calls to export MAT files? The `export` call does not have the option of providing that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
from asammdf import MDF ,Signal 

mdf=MDF(version='4,10')

Signal= mdf.get("name of the signal")
```